# Null pointer exception but variable contains a value

Tags: java

This code gives me a Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException. The exception occurs at the if statement at the bottom of the code.

```
    public boolean printEmployees(Node Head){
    boolean isSuccessful = true;

    Node nodeChecker = new Node();
    nodeChecker = Head;

    int hospitalEmployeeCount = 0;
    int doctorCount = 0;
    int surgeonCount = 0;
    int nurseCount = 0;
    int administratorCount = 0;
    int receptionistCount = 0;
    int janitorCount = 0;
    System.out.println(nodeChecker.getData().getRole());
    while(nodeChecker != null){
        if(nodeChecker.getData().getRole() == "h")
            hospitalEmployeeCount++;
```

Another section of code reads data from a file and fills up a linked list.  I have checked using break points and the linked list is there. nodeChecker points to the head of the linked list and when I call the System.out.println statement it prints h. I cannot figure out why the exception keeps happening.

Later on in this method I attempt to print to screen all of the information in the linked list.  I have tried commenting out this section of code to test the remaining code, but it prints out as if the linked list is empty.  I can check the variables in the linked list all the way up to the end of the function and it shows the data in the correct positions and the correct variables in the list.

Comment: Side note, [don't compare `String` objects with `==`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Possibly the `.getData()` at `nodeChecker.getData().getRole()` returns null value. Also use `.equals()` method to compare string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` and `if`statements towards the bottom of your code need to be fixed.

Look at your while loop, it will stay looping as long as `nodeChecker != null` evaluates to true. However, nothing inside your loop changes its value, so it will always evaluate to true, which can lead to some problems.

At the bottom, in your "if" statement, there are four things which could possibly be null: nodeChecker, getData(), getRole(), or "h".

Since you are in the loop, we already know that nodeChecker is not null. "h" is trivially not null. If getRole() is null, there won't be an exception, because `null == "h"` will just evaluate to false.

Thus, by exclusion, getData() must be evaluating to null.

There are a few ways to get around this issue. One easy way is just adding an extra term in your if statement, as follows:

```
Data data = nodeChecker.getData();
if (data != null && data.getRole().equals("h")
```

What this is doing is taking advantage of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation. Basically, if data == null, the LHS of the if statement will evaluate to false. Since it is an "and" statement, since the LHS is false, the statement cannot equal true, so the RHS will not bother to evaluate. If data != null, the LHS would then equal true, and the RHS will be evaluated. This protects from the null exception which comes from calling the `getRole()` method on a null object.

Also, make sure that you are using `.equals()` to check string equality, since "==" checks the equality of the references, while ".equals()" checks the equality of the value.

Answer (score 4):

`nodeChecker` is not `null` but `nodeChecker.getData()` is `null`, also `String` comparison [is done incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: Keep in mind that nodeChecker.getData().getRole() can also return NULL.

Comment: @Sou if `nodeChecker.getData().getRole()` is `null` then it won't throw `NullPointerException`

Comment: @Soumya: nodeChecker.getData().getRole() returning null will not result in null pointer exception but if condition failure.

Comment: I don't see what could be wrong with nodeChecker.getData().getRole(), because when I use it in the print statement it prints an h to screen.

Comment: @user that is outside of loop